# Scala sum of the arrays contained in an array

Tags: arrays, scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have defined a function that receives an array of arrays. I want to get the sum of all arrays. My question is how to make that sum.

```
def suma[T](args: WrappedArray[T]*)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
    args.transpose.map(_.sum)
} 
def sum[T](arr: WrappedArray[WrappedArray[T]])(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
    val result = suma( ______ )
}
```

I thought I use the defined "sum" , but not how to pass the contents of the container array. Like there is a much simpler way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "sum of all arrays" you want `.flatten`, not `.transpose`.
`args.flatten.sum` should do it.

Or are you asking how to call a function with vargargs? For that, you need a *splat* operator: 
`val result = suma(arr:_*)`